# Silently install Microsoft Edge Webview 2, which return value indicates that a newer version is installed?

Tags: microsoft-edge, .net-framework, windows-installer, setup, silent-install

I am currently trying to install Microsoft Edge Webview2 Evergreen installer silently. For that purpose, I call

```
MicrosoftEdgewebview2RuntimeInstallerX64.exe /silent /install
```

in a script. This works, however I would like to get the different failure states and react accordingly.

Currently, the installer quites with a return code of 0 if it was successful, and 1 if it was not. However, I would like to know the reason why it failed. It will return 1 for example when a newer version is already installed, which is not really an error case in my scenario. It will also return 1 when the installation fails for another reason.

So how can I determine the state of the Installer after installation? Compared to the Dot Net setups from Microsoft that give error codes like 1638 (already installed), I do not get that detailed codes from the Edge Webview 2 setup.

Is there any way to get the different return states silently and process them in a scripting context?

Comment: You could parse the installation log, outside of that, if the installer doesn't provide different return codes not much you can do about it.

Comment: If the installer gives an error message without the `/silent` parameter, you could redirect to a file and process using `findstr`.